# Как упаковать несколько файлов в zip,которые лежат в разных папках?

Tags: c#, zip

Есть `List<string>` в котором содержатся пути(Path) всех файлов, которые я хочу упаковать.

Проблема в том что эти файлы в разных папках. Можно как то скопировать их в новую папку, а потом их упаковать, но количество этих файлов очень велико, так неудобно.

Есть ли какой нибудь способ?

Код создания архива:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zip.AddDirectory(@"C:\project\");
    zip.AddFile(@"c:\Temp\Import.csv");
    zip.Save(@"C:\Temp\PackedProject.zip");
}
```

Comment: Каким образом создаете архив?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведенный вами код, к сожалению, не работоспособен. Класс `ZipFile` есть в библиотеке классов, но он статический и не рекомендован Microsoft для использования в приложениях для Windows Store, там же рекомендовано использовать класс `ZipArchive`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)

Если полные имена (путь+имя) файлов уже содержатся в `List<string> fileNames`, то не важно в каких папках они находятся, главное чтобы были права на чтение этих файлов. Если все условия выполнены, то дальше все довольно просто:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"newArchive.zip", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
  using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
  {
    foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
    {
      FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName)
      ZipArchiveEntry fileEntry = archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fi.FullName,fi.Name,CompressionLevel.Optimal);            
    }
  }
}
```

как-то так. Более подробно читать в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx)

Можно улучшить результат если собирать файлы не в `string`, а сразу в `FileInfo` и `List<FileInfo>` соответственно. Преимущество использования 'FileInfo' для хранения информации о файлах заключается в том, что есть ряд методов получения уже готовых коллекций этих объектов, например как дочерние узлы `DirectoryInfo`, и "из коробки" получаем легкие манипуляции с именами файлов. как то выделение пути из полного имени, получение только имени без пути плюс дополнительная функциональность, которая может внезапно понадобиться при работе с файлом. например уточнить права доступа.

Comment: а чем результат с использованием `List<FileInfo>` лучше использования списка строк?

Comment: @Bald не надо `FileInfo` создавать. Очевидно же :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov так разве его не надо создавать раньше что бы передать этот самый `List<FileInfo>`? или я чего то не понимаю? я например в это случае передаю `Dictionary<string, string>`(имя файла, путь)

Comment: @Bald некоторые способы получения списка файлов дают сразу FileInfo

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну если на выходе `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` тогда согласен

Comment: я смотрю уже без меня договорились =) @Bald `FileInfo` легко получается из файла и не приходится мудрить с разбиением строки полного имени на имя и путь, это не сложно, просто громоздко получается. плюс как уже сказали `FileInfo` можно получать готовыми коллекциями, как дочерние узлы папки или результаты поиска.